# Weird order of sequence in Oracle DB + Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

The Hibernate annotations of the entity class look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ENTRY")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_MY_ENTRY_ID", allocationSize=1, sequenceName="SEQ_MY_ENTRY_ID")
public class MyEntry {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_MY_ENTRY_ID")
private Long id;

...
```

The SQL for the Oracle DB looks like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQ_MY_ENTRY_ID" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1541 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE;
```

It works fine!

I just wonder why the generated IDs seem to be in chaotic order. I'd expect something like `1148, 1149, 1150, ...`. But instead I get e.g. this: `1148, 1165, 1166, 1181, 1167, 1149, 1150, 1182, 1151, 1168, 1152, 1153, 1183, 1154, ...`. Again, it works fine. It never leads to a conflict. But why this strange order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle sequence caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381681/oracle-sequence-caching)

Comment: Are you working on RAC?

Comment: @mustaccio I don't think it's related. I don't have any gaps in my sequence.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Actually I don't know what our Oracle DB is running on.

Comment: You _"expect something like 1148, 1149, 1150"_ but instead you get _"this  1148, 1165, 1166, 1181"_ -- if your question is not about gaps, then what is it about?

Comment: @mustaccio: the sequence caching happens on the server side in Oracle, it's not cached per connection. I would rather suspect a RAC setup here

Comment: @mustaccio On the first view it looks like gaps. But later on the sequence all gaps close. In the sequence is 1148, 1149 and 1150 - just not in the expected order. It seems like it is running several subsequent parts of the sequence in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you described, i.e. unordered ID suggests, that you are connected to a RAC database.

You may verify this with the query

```
select name, value from v$parameter where name='cluster_database';
```

If the VALUE is TRUE, you are connected to RAC. In this case each instance allocates its own cache interval and dependent on what instance calls the NEXTVAL a different rance is returned. So if you have two instances and the first cache 1 to 20 and the seconds 21 to 40 you may get e.g. 1,2,21,3,4,22,23,...

Check the attibute `ORDER_FLAG` of the sequence

```
select SEQUENCE_NAME, ORDER_FLAG from user_sequences;
```

you will see most probably 'N'.

You may suppress this unordered allocation setting the seqeunce to `ORDER` allocation, but be prepared that it effectivelly suppress the caching as well (and may cause a contention).

```
 alter sequence seq1 order;
```

Additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866959/oracle-rac-and-sequences) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513936/oracle-sequence-value-are-not-ordered)

Comment: Thank you Marmite! Unfortunately I can't check it before Monday.

Comment: My architect confirmed that we use an RAC cluster. What you explained makes sense to me, although the query `select name, value from v$parameter where name='cluster_database';` just resulted in an error. But I might not have the rights like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924681/cannot-find-table-vparameter-in-oracle.